# Bolt CMS - posix_getuid()

Tags: bolt-cms

I've seen that there are other bugs which mention this issue but I think this one is slightly different. I have 3 folders in the `files` directory and when using the file manager I can access the first folder `2015-04` fine and as expected. However when I attempt to access the other two folders `2015-05` and `2015-06` I receive the following error.

`Call to undefined function Bolt\Filesystem\posix_getuid()`

If this is a result of PHP `posix` not being installed, then why can I access the first folder fine. Which is what leads me to think the issue is something else, but I could be wrong.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is `php-posix` not being installed causing the error to be thrown.

The `posix_getuid()` function is called to check file read/write access under certain circumstances.

The `files/` folder is checked fairly early in the bootstrap, and I am guessing that `2015-04` has read/write and that `2015-05` and `2015-06` allow read, but not write access to the web server's user context.

There was a workaround for this fairly late in 2.1.x from memory, but you're better off to install/enable the POSIX extension if at all possible.